# Angular href with multiple views on mulitple controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem on AngularJS with simple task. My framework use a multiple views in every controller. I need to make a simple link via ng-click from one view on controller1 to another subview on controller2. This second subview calls with method  that is in the second controller. This method use POST to parse values from ng-repeat.
I tried to combine href and ng-click with that method but this combination triggers the first method, and then href link. On this way link lead to frst view on the controller2 and  can't access my subview. How to make to trigger first href and then method?

Also use $routeProvider in framwork.

**HTML**

```
<a ng-controller="controller2" href="#checkouts" ng-repeat="classs in classes | object2Array | orderBy: 'className' track by $index " ng-click="addByClass(classs.id)">{{classs.className}}</a>
```

**app.js** **controller2**

```
 $scope.addByClass = function(id){ 
     showHideLoad();
     dataFactory.httpRequest('checkouts/addByClass/'+id,'POST').then(function(data) {

         $scope.class = data.class ;
         $scope.changeView('addByClass');
         showHideLoad(true);
          });
```

Comment: $location.path('/route'); inject $location in your controller

Comment: @Vicky Smart Could you, please explain it with more details. Thanks

Comment: Can You copy and paste your .config in ... app.js

Comment: app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
      controller  : 'dashboardController'
    })
  .when('/checkouts', {
      templateUrl : 'templates/checkouts.html',
      controller  : 'checkoutsController'
    })   .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/'
    });

});